# How to push object inside array laravel php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to define an array and add elements to it, but there's a problem with that

```
        $prodectsum =  array();
```

```
               $prodectsum->push((object)['name' => 'mmm', 'color' => 'red']);
```

Define an array in Laravel

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: `->push()` is a [`Collection` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-push), but you're using an Array. Either use a `Collection` (i.e. `$productSum = collect()`, or use `array_push` (or shorthand syntax `$productsum[] = (object)[...];`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array()
$newArray[] = $someObject;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Arr::add() or Arr::set() from Laravel Helpers.
See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-add